# Views PDF CSS file not being applied on generated PDF

Tags: theming, views

I've created a pdf display with views_pdf module in views, and under the PDF SETTINGS i've included a CSS File (eg. sites/all/themes/custom/mytheme/css/mytheme.css).

When viewing the page display of the view, the css is being applied, but when viewing the generated pdf, all of the css is missing. 
I have tried putting inline css as well but it's not working.

Can someone tell me what is the workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to rewrite the field. For the title field it would be something like:

```
<div class="pdf-title">[title]</div>
```

And then use this custom class in my CSS file.